# Sharepoint 2013 remove the apps icon

Tags: 2013, button

Sorry to be asking another question but in SharePoint 2013 how do I hide the top left apps button across all pages including mysites?

[image]

Many Thanks

Comment: I think that there is no **app launcher** in Sharepoint 2013 it's just in **SharePoint Online** and **SharePoint 2016 On-premise** .

Comment: Oh god, I'm really sorry for all the typos. Just under a little bit of stress at the moment. Also your right I'm using 2016 on-premise, I've had it in my head I'm using 2013.